# Generate random map for tile world

Tags: c#, random, xna, tiles

Platform game in C# / XNA.

I have a `int[,]` array that I fill for example:

```
int[,] {
  {0, 0, 0, 1},
  {0, 0, 1, 2},
  {0, 1, 2, 2},
  {1, 2, 2, 2},
}
```

Output:

```
[air][air][air][grass]
[air][air][grass][dirt]
[air][grass][dirt][dirt]
[grass][dirt][dirt][dirt]
```

Now I have a random function that fills the int array:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
  for (int x = 0; x < 23; x++)
  {
     tiles[i, x] = rnd.Next(0, 3);
  }
}
```

output:

[image: Platformer Example]

What is a good algorithm to generate the map properly? Like above 45% more air and on top of dirt I want grass.

Comment: You could apply some [random distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution).

Comment: Map generation is pretty broad subject. This was asked already (e.g. [click](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/18735)). Easy thing to do is to start with initial *plain* map which have certain level of ground (e.g. 5 blocks height) and then your algorithm simply go through it (sequentially or randomly) and generates holes, hills, mountains, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with the probabilities like this, for example:

```
int r=rnd.Next(0,100);
tile= (r < 50) ? 0 : (r < 75) ? 1 : 2;
```

Make the 50 and 75 variables for even more fun.